# How can we get the updated document in response on calling updateOne

Tags: mongodb, go

Below is the json document that i want to update for some id

```
{
    "_id": "some_id",
    "counter": {
        "$incr": 1,
    },
}
```

after using the above bson for update with the help of library (github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) it will increment the counter value by 1 in the collection for the field counter.

How can I get the updated result without querying again, or without acquiring a lock?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the `findOneAndUpdate` command and set option to return documents after the update is performed.

Query:

```
err = collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
        ctx,
        bson.D{},  // <- Find block
        bson.D{{
            "$inc", bson.D{{  // <- update block
                "counter", 1,
            }},
        }},
        options.FindOneAndUpdate().SetReturnDocument(options.After),  // <- Set option to return document after update (important)
    ).Decode(&result)  // <- Save document to variable
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation

You should set the new option to true to return the document after update was applied.

```
 Character.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, { new: true });
```